# When I create files the owner / group is always root

Tags: linux, permissions, ownership

On Linux, I am logged in as another user, I have added myself to wheel.

```
wheel:x:10:root,allan
```

I have uncommented the lines of `/etc/sudoers`

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere 
root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL

## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL

## Same thing without a password
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

However, when I create a file e.g.

```
touch test
```

the owner and group of file 'test' are:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root     0 Jul 28 09:05 test
```

It seems like I have to run `sudo` in front of every command, otherwise I get permission denied errors.

How do I go about resolving this?

Comment: What's the permissions of that directory where you do `touch test`?

Comment: Are you in a root shell when you `touch test`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't resolve it; the system is behaving as expected.  The sudoers file controls the sudo command, it does not change the way the kernel interprets file and directory permissions.  In order to get the effects of sudo, you must run sudo.  What sudo does is run commands as root, so naturally files created by a sudo-run command are owned by root.